# Flutter App crashes when creating Document with a List of Lists

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I try to add a List of Lists to a Firestore Document my App crashes without an error.

```
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Test").add({
  "test": [
    ["1", "2"],
    ["3"], ["4"]
  ]
});
```

Is this an issue with Firebase or am I missing something here?

Comment: I tried to add this to Firestore console, there no possibility to add an array inside an array

Answer (score 1):

You can not add arrays in arrays... But there is a way to achieve the thing you wanna do by inserting a map in between :

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Test").add({
  "test": [
    {"1": ["1", "2"]},
    {"2": ["3"]},
    {"3": ["4"]},
  ]
});
```

or a map of arrays:

```dart
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("Test").add({
  "arrays": {
    ["1", "2"],
    ["3"],
    ["4"],
  }
});
```

Comment: Ah thats really annoying and doesn't make sense to me why firebase won't allow it but thanks for your recommendation.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you

Answer (score 1):

That's a lot to do with the fact that Firestore "arrays" are ABSOLUTELY NOT ARRAYS. They are ORDERED LISTS, generally in the order they were added to the array. The SDK presents them to the CLIENT as arrays, but Firestore itself does not STORE them as actual arrays - THE NUMBER YOU SEE IN THE CONSOLE is the order, not an index. Matching elements in an array (arrayContains, e.g.) requires matching the WHOLE element - if you store an ordered list of objects, you CANNOT query the "array" on sub-elements.

The client SDKs generally present the values in the arrays/"ordered lists" to you as an array - which has more to do with most languages not having a primitive element that is an ordered list.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying! My work around is to convert the inner list into a string separated by '#'.